# How to decide which interval fits best?

Tags: c, algorithm, logic, dynamic-programming, greedy

I have an assignmnent and I'm having a little bit of trouble. I have a set of numbers and a set of intervals and I need to decide which intervals I need to use to incorporate all of my numbers. So far so good, I've managed to obtain the intervals that contain my numbers but when it comes to choosing just 1, the more efficient one, I don't really know how to do it. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
int min, max;
short int added;
}Pair;

int main(){

FILE *fin, *fout;
fin = fopen("points.in", "r");

if (fin == NULL){
    perror("Error");
    return 1;
}

int n, m;
int i = 0, j, res;
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &m);
int points[n];
Pair p[m];
while (i != n){
    fscanf(fin, "%d", &points[i]);
    i++;
}

i = 0;

while (i != m){
    fscanf(fin, "%d %d", &p[i].min, &p[i].max);
    p[i].added = 0;
    i++;
}

Pair swap;
for (i = 0; i < m-1; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < m-i-1; j++){
    if (p[j].min > p[j+1].min){
        swap = p[j];
        p[j] = p[j+1];
        p[j+1] = swap;
    }
}

fout = fopen("points.out", "w");

if (fout == NULL){
    perror("Error");
    return 1;
}

int k = 0, dist = 0, poz;
j = 0;
i = 0;
while (i < n){
    if (points[i] <= p[j].max && points[i] >= p[j].min){
        dist = p[j].max - p[j].min;
        poz = j;
        while(points[i] <= p[j].max && points[i] >= p[j].min){
            if ( dist < (p[j].max - p[j].min) ){
                dist = p[j].max - p[j].min;
                poz = j;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    if (p[poz].added == 0){
            p[poz].added = 1;
            k++;
        }
    if (points[i] <= p[poz].max && points[i] >= p[poz].min)
        while(points[i] <= p[poz].max && points[i] >= p[poz].min){
            i++;
        }
    else i++;
}
res = k;

fprintf(fout, "%d", res);
fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm doing it wrong? Basically, my intuition tells me that I need to chose a starting value, find the interval that it fits in and then iterate through all the intervals that can fit that variable, and choose the one that has the highest "value" for me. What I mean si that it can incorporate more values, e.g. I will choose [1,6] over [0,1] if my value is 1. 1 is in both intervals but I have more chances with [1,6].

Comment: My code is written in C and I thought that it would be needed to put the tag. I'm sorry if I made a mistake. I'm relatively new.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya This is C code. The C tag is appropriate.

Comment: Certainly you have all the code necessary to make a simple small compilable program that demos your issue.  Posting that helps others help you.  Recommend to add that code to gain more helpful answers and comments - unless your goal is to make it hard for others?

Comment: A key logic weakness is rating "best" by the smallness `sol[j].max - sol[j].min` on a point by point basis.  I suspect code needs to also keep track of the min and max `points[i]` found so far.  If only 1 interval needed, why not just use the min/max of `points[]` and find the "smallest" interval that holds those two?

Comment: I've added the whole code so that it should be easy to understand. The problem that I am having is that I'm not getting all the intervals that are needed. What I'm being asked is: given N numbers and M intervals, find the minimum number of intervals that include all N numbers